# How to import module inside package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-import, pep328

Folder structure:

```
foo/
  bar.py
  __init__.py
test.py
```

`foo/__init__.py` has `import bar`

I am running `test.py` which has `import foo`

---

How do I get `__init__.py` to import `bar.py`?

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

Why does Python not create a new scope for my package and make the root for imports the `foo` directory?

Relative paths seem to not work either (I'm receiving a `SyntaxError`), although I'm looking for a solution that allows absolute paths.

```
import .bar
```

---

Two unacceptable answers:

- I can't use `import foo.bar`. I need the `foo` package to have its own independent layer/scope so I can move it around anywhere in my computer and import it from anywhere. This means the root could change and `import foo.bar` will not always work.
- I can't add the `foo` folder to my path. Obviously this would clutter the path and name conflicts could easily happen. Commence sense would say that this package's files should be separated from the path of what's using it.

---

Maybe there's a solution to add this package's directory to the path only for the scope of that package, somewhere in `__init__.py`?

Comment: `from . import bar` is the correct syntax

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll use that for now. I still would like a solution that doesn't require relative paths.

Comment: @DavidCallanan: You say you don't want relative paths, but you also reject `import foo.bar`, which is the correct way to do absolute path imports. `import X` is *always* absolute; you must use `from .Y import X` (where `Y` might be nothing if you're importing a sibling module/package) if you want relative imports, per [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

Comment: @ShadowRanger. Beat me to it

Comment: @MadPhysicist `import foo.bar` is an absolute path, but it's still relative to the project root. It's still not truly absolute, I don't have to type `"C:/Users/Me/Desktop/etc/etc"`. In the same way I was expecting `import bar` to be an absolute path, but relative to the package root instead of project root, makes more sense to me.

Comment: @DavidCallanan: It's absolute, in the sense that it must be rooted in a directory listed in `sys.path` (I don't know what you mean by "project root", because that's not a concept separate from "package root"). If `foo` is in the working directory (implicitly the first entry in `sys.path`) or otherwise installed in a directory listed in `sys.path`, `import foo` can find it, but `bar` does not appear in any of those directories, so it can't be found with `import bar`. So the consistency is in `import X` always going back to (some directory) in `sys.path`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ah that's how they do it ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), the `import X` syntax is purely for absolute imports; since `bar` is not a top-level module here, the only valid `import X` syntax is `import foo.bar`.

The correct way to import `bar` from `foo`'s `__init__.py` is:

```
from . import bar
```

Your point about wanting "absolute paths", but also wanting something like `import .bar` is impossible; even if `import .bar` worked, that's clearly a relative path (in that it only makes sense relative to the module that executes it; `.bar` would not make sense if imported outside of the `foo` package).

As for "Why does Python not create a new scope for my package and make the root for imports the foo directory?" the simple example is to imagine your sub-module is named `math`, not `bar`. What does:

```
import math
```

mean in this context? If it means your sub-module, how do you get the built-in, top-level `math` module? These problems (which I've encountered in Python 2 code when I failed to include `from __future__ import absolute_import`) are *why* PEP 328 and default absolute imports exist; one syntax is always absolute (removing ambiguity), and you can use the relative import syntax to perform relative imports (also without ambiguity) when needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't want `import .bar`, I was just trying to figure out the relative path syntax because `import bar` didn't work which I tried earlier on in my question. I think Python could have easily added another character e.g. `$` for paths relative to the current package instead of to the current directory or to the project root.

Comment: @DavidCallanan: `.` is relative to the current package (e.g. if you're in `foo/bar/baz.py`, `from . import ...` means "from within `foo.bar`, the package containing the `baz` module"). What Python lacks is a syntax for imports relative to the project/package root (e.g. if you know `eggs` exists as the direct child of your top-level package, you can't import `eggs` w/o either knowing how deep in the package you are [to get appropriate number of dots for relative imports] or what the top-level package's name is [for absolute import]). They didn't add it because you usually know one or the other.

Comment: Yes you always know the relative path if you don't know the absolute, but the relative path gets tedious. I think that was a bad decision, but I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Okay so you are having an error in `__init__.py` file in `import bar` right?
Well this shouldn't blow up but an easy alternate to this is `from . import bar`
**EDIT**

I understood the error occurs due to hierarchy and that `__init__.py` has a top level hierarchy. 
 I found the following [article](https://medium.com/@ramrajchandradevan/python-init-py-modular-imports-81b746e58aae) of great help. Also see [ShadowRanger's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59360856/9855245) answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this for now. I'm still looking for a solution that allows absolute paths.

Comment: I am trying to analyze this more. What you have done should work.

Comment: The error is with `import .bar`, and it absolutely should blow up

Comment: And why would you not expect that to blow up? The parent of `foo` is in the path: `foo` itself is not...

Comment: I am not getting the point. We can obviously import other python scripts in the same directory without relative import. I renamed the `__init__.py` to some other name and then it didn't blew up.

Comment: @DebdutGoswami: Are you using Python 2 by any chance? In Python 2, implicit relative imports were a thing (a thing that caused problems, which is why they aren't a thing in Python 3). [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) fixed that, so on Python 3 (and Py2 with `from __future__ import absolute_import`) `import bar` will only look for a top-level module named `bar`, not a relative name.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes you are right. I typed just `python` instead of `python3`. My apologies. Sorry for all the inconveniences caused.